# Notation for "every member of $A$ is included in some member of $B$"?

Tags: soft-question, notation

I'm studying star refinements of covers in uniform spaces at the moment, and it seems like I'm having to write

> for all $a\in A$ there is some $b\in B$ such that $a\subseteq b$

over and over again. I've been using $A\Subset B$ for this purpose, but I was wondering if there was perhaps a more standard notation for this relationship between sets.

Comment: I can't help much except compression of the mathjax etc. $\forall a\in A, \exists b\in B ,a\subseteq b$

Comment: I think inventing a symbol is just fine.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks, I agree -- I was just curious as to whether or not this relationship had a standard symbol used for it to avoid possible confusion in a paper.

Comment: It is clearly a partial order (or at least a preorder), why not just use $\leq$, which is often used as a generic partial order symbol? Mathematicians are used to repurposing this symbol. Just explain what you mean once.

Comment: @JohnColeman To keep things fancy, then I'd use the partial order symbol $\preceq$ (`\preceq`)

Comment: @JohnColeman Good point, I'll take you up on that.

Comment: @ClementC. That is a good suggestion. On reflection, the order isn't antisymmetric, so perhaps that symbol might be better since using it suggests to the reader that it isn't quite a standard ordering.

Comment: if b is the only one it changes to $! \exists b$ meaning there is exactly one b  in which case it's almost like a function. from a set, to a collection of sets.